# Someone wants me to brew them a batch, what logistics can be used?

Tags: bottling, kegging

I have not seen anything on this subject, but recently I had a beer tasting and there were several people that wanted a batch for parties or weddings.  How do you handle the logistics with such requests?

I talked about a keg, but I do not know how to handle the gas with such a request.

I talked about bottles and I have a lot of them for beer.

What would be the best solution to provide a party of people some home brew when they are asking for it and said they would pay what ever they needed?

Comment: In my state, Texas, only one head of family or unmarried adult can make up to 200 gallons of wine/beer.  This Beer (as defined by the law) can only be transported to a tasting event, where no charge of any kind is made for the beer, only if it is to be part of a tasting for any competition or review.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Corny keg and 3.5ft 3/16 line with picknic tap and small cO2 tank.

In the US you're allowed to produce 200 gallons a year for friends and family use only in a house with two drinking age adults, 100 gallons each. Friends generally can only enjoy it in your home. Transportation and out of home use laws are kinda gray, but usually ok for personal and family use. Competions being an exception.

We are allowed to donate beer to non-profit organizations and they can sell it.

You as a homebrewer cannot sell homemade beer, ever.

Nonprofits can purchase the ingedients for you but that's the limit to an exhange .

Comment: If you got everyone to pay by purchasing the kegs and taps wth the understanding that they need to return them it would be perfectly legal and be a pretty good deal for you.

Comment: @mreff555 basically the way the laws are written a homebrewer cannot profit in anyway, no matter what proxy.